# Reverse Proxy: How to relay (encrypted) SSL traffic to a (decrypted) TCP connection?

Tags: ssl, tcp, proxy, embedded, reverse-proxy

my problem is as follows:

I currently have the following network layout:

```
Embedded Client <-> TCP <-> Server:PortA
```

On top of TCP, there is a proprietary binary protocol. We want to add secure transmission with least effort. So we will modify the client to use SSL on top of TCP. However, we want to keep the server untouched, if possible. So the idea is, to use a proxy that achieves the following:

```
Embedded Client <-> SSL <-> Proxy:PortB <-> TCP <-> Server:PortA
```

The proxy will have the necessary SSL certificate.
The question is, is there any software that allows this type of reverse-proxying that has nothing to do with HTTP? I know there are some proxies like [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [NginX](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), but as far as I know the only support HTTP or a few well defined other protocols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like stunnel is exactly what you want.

Comment: That indeed looks like what I want. I will check that, thanks a lot!